# Live output to a file with PHP exec()?

Tags: php, gulp, shell-exec

On Windows, I use PHP to execute a `gulp` command.

Like this :

```
<?php

     set_time_limit(0);

     exec("cd /projectpath");
     $results = exec("gulp");
?>
```

This works, but I can only get the results of the command after it has finished, which takes about 30 seconds.

I would like to write the results to a file, ***while it is running***, so I can poll the progress in an interval using Ajax.

In a normal command prompt I can do

```
gulp > results.txt 2>&1
```

and the text file is being filled while the command is running.

I already tried `shell_exec`(), `system`() and `passthru`() too, but I can't get this to work from within PHP.

Any idea's ?

Comment: Maybe [popen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call `exec()` in the way you proposed?

```
<?php

     set_time_limit(0);

     exec("cd /projectpath");
     $results = exec("gulp > results.txt 2>&1");
?>
```

Comment: I tried this of course, but the command seems to stop immediately then and does nothing. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`proc_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php):

```
<?php
$cmd = 'for i in $(seq 20); do sleep 1; echo $i; done';
$cwd = '/';
$descriptors = array(
    0 => array('pipe', 'r'),
    1 => array('file', 'stdout', 'w'),
    2 => array('file', 'stderr', 'w'),
);

$handle = proc_open($cmd, $descriptors, $pipes, $cwd);
if (!$handle) {
    echo 'failed to run command';
} else {
    proc_close($handle); // wait for command to finish (optional)
}
```

Comment: I came across this example, but couldn't really understand what was happening in it. Where does this write the results to ? How to use it in my example?

Comment: `$cwd`  should be set to `'/projectpath'`, `$cmd = 'gulp';`, and then replace `stdout` and `stderr` with the filenames where you want to have stdout and stderr.